# Elasticsearch search using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Query using curl.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/users/_search?pretty=true -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
  { 
      "from" : 0, "size" : 5,
      "query" : {
          "query_string" : {
              "query" : "Port"
          }
      }
  }
'
```

Same thing i am trying to do in python requests:

```
url = f'{URL}/{INDEX}/_search/'
es_query = { 
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "Port"
        }
    }
}
res = requests.get(url, data=es_query) 
print(res.json())
```

I am getting below error while doing this.

```
`{'error': 'Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported', 'status': 406}`
```

Please take a look what can be the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use [curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com/python/) to easily convert cURL commands to Python requests. Here's the output for your cURL command:

```
import requests

params = {
    'pretty': 'true',
}

json_data = {
    'from': 0,
    'size': 5,
    'query': {
        'query_string': {
            'query': 'Port',
        },
    },
}

response = requests.get('http://localhost:9200/users/_search', params=params, headers=headers, json=json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong

```
url = f'{URL}/{INDEX}/_bulk/'
```

Should be

```
url = f'{URL}/{INDEX}/_search/'
```

Also you need to specify the following request header

```
Content-type: application/json
```

Like this:

```
res = requests.get(url, json=es_query, headers={"Content-type": "application/json"})
```

Comment: {'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'json_parse_exception', 'reason': "Unrecognized token 'query': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 1, column: 7]"}], 'type': 'json_parse_exception', 'reason': "Unrecognized token 'query': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 1, column: 7]"}, 'status': 400}

Comment: Not getting this error.